# Sharepoint: refresh list item after update

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working on a Sharepoint 2010 project that uses a basic approval workflow. The issue I am facing now is that when I update an item in a list and set it to approved, the changes are not reflected on the website.
The only way I found is to recycle the app pool.... but since content update activities will be managed by a non-dev team, I would rather have another solution.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You shouldn't have to recycle the app pool! Are you caching any content?

Comment: no, or at least I'm not doing it intentionally. I also tried to flush Site collection output cache and Site collection object cache, but nothing changed